# VB: how to compare two objects to find out if the values of their properties are the same?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, compare, equals

I have an object called `Statistics`. Inside this object there are 6 more objects. Each contains properties with values.

So for example, `Statistics(0)` contains an 'age' field, a 'sex' field, 'vehicle' etc...
same goes for `Statistics(1)`, `Statistics(2)` etc...

What I want to do is compare `Statistics(0)` all the way to `Statistics(6)` and find out if any one of them is identical to another.

If all of the fields contained within `Statistics(0)` have the same values as the fields in `Statistics(1)`, I want to do something.

How can I compare these objects to one-another?

**what I have tried**

```
For Each Stat As ExportStatistics In Statistics
    Insert_VehicleStats(Stat) 'Insert values into main Vehicle table 

    If Statistics.Length > 1 Then
    Dim i = 0
    Dim y = 0
    Dim previousObject As ExportStatistics

    For Each Stat2 In Statistics

        If Stat2.Equals(previousObject) Then
            Dim sadXml = "do something"
        End If

       previousObject = Stat2

    Next
End if
```

Comment: Are you requiring that there will be exact alignment i.e. `left.VehicleStatistics(0)` will match exclusively with `right.VehicleStatistics(0)` (and not, say, `right.VehicleStatistics(2)`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the Equals function in your class or overload it then create your own comparison code.  Here's an example (it assumes your object is of type VehicleStatisticsItem):

```
 Public Class VehicleStatisticsItem

  Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
    'Test for type and define tests or just pass to base function
    Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
  End Function

  Public Overloads Function Equals(item As VehicleStatisticsItem) As Boolean
    'Define your tests here
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: If you do that, you may also want to implement `IEquatable(Of T)`.

Answer (score -2):

The 2 objects you are comparing will not equal each other even if their properties do. You need to specify that you are comparing their properties.

Change

```
If vehicleStatistic.Equals(previousObject) Then
        Dim sadXml = "do something"
End If
```

To

```
If vehicleStatistic.GetType().GetProperties.Equals(previousObject.GetType().GetProperties) Then
        Dim sadXml = "do something"
End If
```

This way you are comparing their properties.